# EJB authentication

Tags: java, ejb, jaas

Here is what I'm trying to do: I have an authentication EJB that can grant user a "ticket" (pair of key and token) by validating username and password. Clients should pass the ticket every call to remote EJB and such ticket should be able to be fetched by EJB (method, or interceptor) and EJB/ or interceptor should validate the ticket and determine whether the call is valid or not.

I don't want to add ticket as parameter to each function that requires authentication, and I believe there should be a way to implement this. I've looked through several articles about JAAS custom login module, but still can't find a non-vendor specific way to do this. (And I am trying to avoid vendor specific implementation)

If JAAS can't do the job, is there anything like "header" in EJB?

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just use roles to perform this authorization?  Instead of granting a ticket to a user, assign him a role.

Then, it's just a matter of using the inbuilt functionality of checking whether a user is in a role or not.

Answer (score 0):

Although I agree with @EdH, i.e. use @RunAs, you can accomplish what you want by adding to the EJB context your token.

Red Hat does something similar [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.1/html/Development_Guide/Pass_Additional_Security_For_EJB_Authentication.html) by using the interface [EJBClientInterceptor](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org.jboss/jboss-ejb-client/1.0.14.Final/org/jboss/ejb/client/EJBClientInterceptor.java#EJBClientInterceptor.Registration).
By looking the code of [ReceiverInterceptor](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.jboss/jboss-ejb-client/1.0.0.Final/org/jboss/ejb/client/ReceiverInterceptor.java) (which implements the EJBClientInterceptor) you can see how to modify the EJB context (on the client-side) and add your token:

> context.setReceiverInvocationContext(new
> EJBReceiverInvocationContext(context, receiverContext));
>
> context.sendRequest();